# Using WP just to edit pages of an existing site

Tags: pages, html-editor

I was asked to let the user to edit an existing site articles using Worpress.

But because the site has a lot of php code (not used for the articles) that would take quite a lot to convert in WP plugins, and replicating the actual templates would take some time too, so I was thinking to keep the actual site, and use WP just as a powerful editor, and from within the pages just call some WP function to print the articles text.

I would skip all the WP templating system, all I need is print the article text in the existing pages. The site tree is not going to change.

Is this possible?
Any hints on what to look for?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).